# Squaring a function, getting a surprising result

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm doing a problem in which I have to find the minimum distance between the origin and a point on a parabola. I understand that the minimum of a function and the minimum of the square of the function are the same. The distance function when considering that one point is the origin should be $d =\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$, making the squared function $d = x^2 + y^2$. However, when solving for $y$ so that I can make the equation solely in terms of $x$, I get $y = \sqrt{-x^2}$, and substituting that for $y$ in the original equation would negate that square root and result in $x^2 -x^2$, or $0$. Hopefully I just overlooked something, but that obviously seems wrong if I'm trying to find a distance function I can derive and get a minimum.

Comment: What equation did you solve for $y$ to get it in terms of $x$?

Comment: $x^2 + y^2$. as I noted below I'm starting to think that was the wrong approach.

Comment: Yes, because $x^2+y^2$ is not an equation. What you seem to have solved is $x^2+y^2=0$. But is there any reason to believe that $x^2+y^2$ is equal to zero?

Answer (score 1):

The general point on the parabola $y=x^2$ has *two* coordinates: $(t,t^2)$ for $t$ a real. Use this in the distance squared to $(0,0)$ formula. Multiply out, find derivative, ETC.

I don't think parabola formula is $y=x^2$ since then min distance clearly zero (no work to do). But same idea works if $y=ax^2+bx+c$ where $a \neq 0.$ then general point is $(t,at^2+bt+c)$ and proceed as above.

Note: It just struck me that your problem may have been in using $x,y$ for both the point on the parabola, *and* in applying $x^2+y^2$ for distance to origin. If you keep $x,y$ for the parabola point, then must solve for one of $x,y$ in terms of the other to set things up. That's why a good idea is to use another variable like $t$ to get the parabola parametrized in that new letter, like $(t,t^2+1)$ or what have you. Initially check if $(0,0)$ already on the parabola [if so stop, min distance $0.$] Otherwise in $d^2=x^2+y^2$ you have to *substitute* the coordinates into that, e.g. in my made-up example $t^2+(t^2+1)^2.$ Good luck.

I looked at your example $x^2-2x+5$ and found the same numeric value for $x$ as you mentioned in comments. Then I applied the cubic formula and got that, if $u=\frac{-1+\sqrt{55}}{4},$ then
$$x=u^{1/3}+\frac{3}{2u^{1/3}}+1.$$
A google search should get you to several versions of the cubic formula.

Comment: So, basically, substitute the formula for a parabola into the squared distance formula and derive that? Because I did find another source that corroborates that. For clarification, the parabola is $x^2 - 2x + 5$. It doesn't touch 0,0 but does cross the y-axis.

Comment: Yes, for that one you get $[x]^2+[x$2-2x+5]^2$ for then function to minimize. Remember it's (x-coord)^2 +(y-coord)^2 for squared distance to origin.

Comment: @MinimumCarnage I worked it out, and since it's fourth degree a cubic results from the derivative, which unfortunately has no rational zeros. Numerically $x$ turns out to be about $-.889$ and resulting min distance (after squareroot of squared distance) about $4.09.$

Comment: One of the first steps of the problem was to graph the parabola and visually estimate the closest point. When I looked at it it looked like the closest point was somewhere just to the left of +1, and your answer is about the same distance away from -1. However, at +1 approximately equals 4 and at -1 approx. 8. Therefore, intuitively I assume that the minimum is at positive x value. Is there a way to prove this mathematically or use the cubic formula to get that result?

Comment: @MinimumCarnage I looked at my notes and found I had $x+2+2x+5$ instead of $x^2-2x+5.$ So that means the sign of $x$ has to be changed in my result of above comment, which then agrees with yours. I also worked on finding the exact expression for $x$ using the cubic formula, and got it. I'll probably add that to my answer.

Comment: @MinimumCarnage In above comment I meant I had $x^2+2x+5$

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the distance between a point on the parabola and the origin, all you have to do is use the Pythagorean theorem (essentially the distance equation you used) to figure out the hypotenuse connecting the points. For example, if the point on the parabola is $(3,9)$, then the distance between $(0,0)$ and $(3,9)$ is $\sqrt{3^2+9^2}=\sqrt{90}=3\sqrt{10}$